# I want to use Cyrillic in my document

Tags: cyrillic

I want to use the Cyrillic alphabet in my document, but the Russian words never compile. Here's the code I'm using:

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5250f987c4d3fb9d3e001233

As you can see, my name isn't showing up.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). What is `\texttrajan`?

Comment: I'm currently getting a crash course in LaTex, so I honestly don't know what a lot of the code does... yet.

Answer (score 5):

This works. I removed the inessential packages that are only confusing. The title page should not use increased leading, just use `\begin{singlespace}` and `\end{singlespace}` around it.

The problem of the mysterious `\mbox{}` is just because vertical space normally is removed at the beginning of a new page; use `\vspace*` for vertical space that doesn't disappear.

Setting `\fontsize{40}{0}` is simply wrong: the spacing between the lines will be terrible. Use the standard commands.

Now the main question: what is `\texttrajan`? There is a font called Trajan in the TeX distribution, that's modelled on the inscriptions on the Trajan column and someone may consider it for a title page. The font has, of course, only uppercase letters and, surely enough, no Cyrillic version, as the Cyrillic script began its existence nearly eight centuries after the building of the Trajan column.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[
 paperwidth=5in,
 paperheight=8in,
 top=0.75in,
 bottom=0.75in,
 inner=0.75in,
 outer=0.75in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc} %These three packages are necessary for the Cyrillic alphabet.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %These packages work in LaTex, not XeLaTex
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 

%END PREAMBLE%

%BOOK STARTS HERE%

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
{\Huge
 Либертарианские уроки \\
\textit{Южного Парка}\\
}

\vspace{\stretch{1}}

{\Large
Libertarian Philosophy in \\
\textit{South Park}\\
}

\vspace{\stretch{4}}

Брандон Симпсон

\end{center}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now the \textit{} command isn't working anywhere. Did I put something in the preamble that conflicts with it?

Comment: @BrandonSimpson I don't know what to say: in my example it works

Answer (score 2):

use `xelatex` or `lualatex` then it is easier to mix different languages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=8in,
 top=0.75in,  bottom=0.75in,
 inner=0.75in,outer=0.75in ]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[russian]{babel} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{\stretch{2}}
\begin{center}
\huge
 Либертарианские уроки \\
\textit{Южного Парка}

\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\Large
Libertarian Philosophy in \\
\textit{South Park}

\vspace{\stretch{4}}
\normalsize
Брандон Симпсон
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does \stretch{1} do?

Comment: in this case it is like a `\vfill`

Comment: I'm getting a crash course in LaTeX from an author with whom I'm writing a book.